# Html.Raw doesn't close empty elements

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, xhtml

Using ASP.Net MVC 4 I have the following in a view:

@Html.Raw("<br />")

In the render page I only get:

<br>

(Note the tag is not closed - this happens with any empty element.)

While I appreciate that this is still valid HTML, it's not valid XHTML.

Is there any way I can get it rendered with the closing '/'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering depends on your doctype. If you set your doctype to XHTML-strict ASP.NET should render it correctly.

I'm guessing your doctype is set to HTML 5, and thus ASP.NET renders it as efficiently as possibly.

Of course, the easiest way to fix it is to just not use `Html.Raw` and just emit it as is.

Comment: Many thanks.

In reality the HTML is coming from my model. I only hard-coded it to simplify the example.